# csvsimple filtering problem

Tags: conditionals, csv, csvsimple

The following code works as I would expect.

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{csvsimple,filecontents}

\begin{document} 

\begin{filecontents*}{chunk.csv}
AAAA,aaaaa
BBBB,bbbbb
CCCC,ccccc
DDDD,ddddd
EEEE,eeeee
FFFFF,fffffff
GGGGG,ggggg
HHHHHH,hhhhh
\end{filecontents*}

\csvreader[no head,before filter= \ifthenelse{\thecsvrow<4}{\csvfilteraccept}{\csvfilterreject}]{chunk.csv}{}{%
\begin{itemize} 
\item \csvcoli , \csvcolii
\end{itemize}}

\end{document}
```

When I change the filter condition from "`\thecsvrow<4`" to "`\thecsvrow=4`" or "`\thecsvrow>4`" the code breaks. Pointers as to how to make this work would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Note that "as expected" here is incorrect, since `\thecsvrow<4` should (intuitively) only print 3 rows while it actually prints 2. You should use `\value{csvrow}<4` instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The per-item testing should be performed when setting the item, rather than in the header, since the filter are set globally. From the [`csvsimple`](http://ctan.org/pkg/csvsimple) [documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/csvsimple/csvsimple.pdf):

> `\csvfilterreject`
>
> All following data lines will be ignored. This command overwrites all previous filter settings.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{csvsimple,filecontents}% http://ctan.org/pkg/{csvsimple,filecontents}

\begin{document} 

\begin{filecontents*}{chunk.csv}
AAAA,aaaaa
BBBB,bbbbb
CCCC,ccccc
DDDD,ddddd
EEEE,eeeee
FFFFF,fffffff
GGGGG,ggggg
HHHHHH,hhhhh
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{itemize}
\csvreader[no head]{chunk.csv}{}{\ifnum\value{csvrow}<4\relax\item \csvcoli, \csvcolii\fi}
\end{itemize}

\hrulefill

\begin{itemize}
\csvreader[no head]{chunk.csv}{}{\ifnum\value{csvrow}=4\relax\item \csvcoli, \csvcolii\fi}
\end{itemize}

\hrulefill

\begin{itemize}
\csvreader[no head]{chunk.csv}{}{\ifnum\value{csvrow}>4\relax\item \csvcoli, \csvcolii\fi}
\end{itemize}

\end{document}
```

Low-level conditionals are used to (not) print each item, testing the value of `csvrow`.

---

Here is an alternative option using [`datatool`](http://ctan.org/pkg/datatool). The interface is very similar, and the transition should therefore not be a problem:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{datatool,filecontents}% http://ctan.org/pkg/{datatool,filecontents}

\begin{document} 

\begin{filecontents*}{chunk.csv}
AAAA,aaaaa
BBBB,bbbbb
CCCC,ccccc
DDDD,ddddd
EEEE,eeeee
FFFFF,fffffff
GGGGG,ggggg
HHHHHH,hhhhh
\end{filecontents*}

\DTLloaddb[noheader,keys={first,last}]{chunk}{chunk.csv}
\begin{itemize}
  \DTLforeach{chunk}{\First=first,\Last=last}{\ifnum\value{DTLrowi}<4\relax\item \First, \Last\fi}
\end{itemize}

\hrulefill

\begin{itemize}
  \DTLforeach{chunk}{\First=first,\Last=last}{\ifnum\value{DTLrowi}=4\relax\item \First, \Last\fi}
\end{itemize}

\hrulefill

\begin{itemize}
  \DTLforeach{chunk}{\First=first,\Last=last}{\ifnum\value{DTLrowi}>4\relax\item \First, \Last\fi}
\end{itemize}

\end{document}
```

Low-level conditionals are used to (not) print each item, testing the value of `DTLrowi`.

Answer (score 3):

The `csvrow` counter is used for *accepted* input lines (after filtering). If you want to count line numbers of the input file to build a filter on it, you should use the counter `csvinputline`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{csvsimple,filecontents}

\begin{document}

\begin{filecontents*}{chunk.csv}
AAAA,aaaaa
BBBB,bbbbb
CCCC,ccccc
DDDD,ddddd
EEEE,eeeee
FFFFF,fffffff
GGGGG,ggggg
HHHHHH,hhhhh
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{itemize}
\csvreader[no head,filter={\value{csvinputline}<4}]{chunk.csv}{}{\item \csvcoli, \csvcolii}
\end{itemize}

\hrulefill

\begin{itemize}
\csvreader[no head,filter={\value{csvinputline}=4}]{chunk.csv}{}{\item \csvcoli, \csvcolii}
\end{itemize}

\hrulefill

\begin{itemize}
\csvreader[no head,filter={\value{csvinputline}>4}]{chunk.csv}{}{\item \csvcoli, \csvcolii}
\end{itemize}

\end{document}
```

The resulting output is the same as in the answer of @Werner.